# Relationship between vector bundles and modules

Tags: vector-bundles, modules, geometric-invariant-theory, geometric-representation-theory, grothendieck-rings

> THE GROTHENDIECK RING IN GEOMETRY AND TOPOLOGY - M.F. ATIYAH
>
> §1. The Grothendieck ring in homotopy theory
>
> I am going to be talking about vector bundles, i.e. fibre bundles with
> fibre a vector space and group the linear group. Vector bundles are to
> the geometer what representations or modules are to the algebraist. In
> fact the modern algebraic geometer hardly distinguishes between the
> two.
>
> [Sir Michael Atiyah, ICM 1962]

Can anyone clarify this quote from Atiyah? (I couldn't find any source)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%E2%80%93Swan_theorem

Comment: He's talking about the correspondence between vector bundles on $X$ and locally free sheaves of $O_X$-modules (and being cavalier by omitting the words "locally free"). See e.g. this careful writeup: https://huettenhain.net/written/scripts/vector-bundles.pdf